# iMac mid 2011 wont let me left click - tried to fix and now stuck in reboot loop

Tags: imac, mouse, click

I have checked many similar questions, but none answers my problem.
I have an iMac mid-2011 running High Sierra, and for some reason this morning, the mouse cursor moves around the screen but I can not left click anything. The right click works fine and I can right click stuff. I tried connecting different mice, and every one that I connect has the same problem but they work fine on other computers (I don't have any additional Bluetooth mice connected to the computer like some people had in their questions.)

I tried the NVRAM reset, but no success. I tried the NVRAM again and now the Mac is stuck in a reboot loop.

I was able to open recovery app with cmd alt r, and the interesting thing, is when the wifi selection screen pops up, I can use the right and left click of the mouse, but as soon as the recovery app loads, again I can not use the left click....

So I am not sure how I can fix this..seems like the only fix is opening the mac, and changing hdds to install a new OS and see if that helps..

Any other suggestions are welcome though

Comment: Check all the available startup modes: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255. Definitely reset your SMC.

Comment: tried all, nothing helps...guess it's hello to reinstalling OS